# What is the smallest number of bingo boards that will guarantee at least one perfect game?

Tags: combinatorics

First, some definitions:

A bingo board is a $5 \times 5$ square grids of cells, each cell containing a number between $1$ and $75$, inclusive. No numbers may be repeated on a single board.

A perfect game is any game where a vertical, horizontal, or diagonal is fully filled in on the grid (i.e. a bingo) after exactly $5$ numbers are called. Numbers are called randomly without replacement.

For the sake of this question, assume that any of the $75$ numbers can appear anywhere on the board and there is no free space in the middle. This differs from common versions of bingo that have a free space and only have a pool of $15$ numbers for each column (such a board restriction cannot be guaranteed to generate a winning board in $5$ calls; it requires at least $16$ calls to guarantee a win on any of the $(^{15}\!P_{4})(^{15}\!P_{5})^4$ possible boards).

**What is the minimum size of a carefully constructed set of boards required to guarantee that at least one of them will win after the $5$th number is called, regardless of which $5$ numbers are called?**

I can reason intuitively that you wouldn't need all $^{75}\!P_{25}$ possible bingo boards as because each row, column, and diagonal could be in any order and still win (cutting down the minimum set by a factor of $2(5!)^5 + 2(5!)$ if my math is correct*), and you could eliminate reflections and rotations for another factor of $8$, but I suspect there might be something more clever that could be done to shrink the set even further.

Bonus: Can a formula be generalized to $N \times N$ boards created using $K$ numbers where $K \geq N^2$? (I imagine using a smaller scale might be helpful to understand the $5 \times 5$ variant anyway)

<sub>* $(5!)^5$ for rows and for columns (since you could rearrange multiple rows or columns at a time, but not a row and a column at the same time), plus $5!$ for each diagonal.</sub>

Comment: This seems like a problem that is solvable with Block diagrams or maybe Transversal diagrams. You want all possible outcomes of $\dbinom{75}{5}$ to be covered in some row, some column, or some diagonal of a bingo card. An upper bound would clearly be $\dfrac{1}{5}\dbinom{75}{5}$ cards where every card chooses 5 disjoint combinations of five numbers as the rows. Likely, the answer is at least $$\dfrac{1}{12}\dbinom{75}{5}$$. This is where every card covers 12 of the $\dbinom{75}{5}$ possible combinations. So, that probably gives some pretty good bounds.

Comment: Regarding “Likely”: yes, $\binom{75}{5}/12$ is a valid lower bound.